# Unregistered Subclass error in PHP

Tags: php, class, parse-platform

I am trying to call [parse.com](http://www.parse.com) API using PHP

When I try to run following code:

```
require_once( 'autoload.php' );
use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseObject;
use Parse\ParseQuery;
use Parse\ParseACL;
use Parse\ParsePush;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseInstallation;
use Parse\ParseException;
use Parse\ParseAnalytics;
use Parse\ParseFile;
use Parse\ParseCloud;

$query = ParseInstallation::query();
$query->equalTo("playerId", "Azee");
ParsePush::send(array(
  "where" => $query,
  "data" => array(
    "alert" => "You have levelled up!"
  )
));
```

I get following error:

```
Cannot create a query for an unregistered subclass.
```

This is really doing my head in! :( I have been searching for hours and I do not see any online resource about it...

Has anyone here encountered this? Any pointers on what I am doing wrong is very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following as seen in the [Parse PHP SDK readme file](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk/blob/master/README.md).

> ## Initialization
>
> After including the required files from the SDK, you need to initalize the ParseClient using your Parse API keys:
>
> ```
> ParseClient::initialize( $app_id, $rest_key, $master_key );
> ```

Looking through the source, I saw that if you don't call this method, then none of the built-in classes get registered, so using them in any way will make the library think they are foreign and throw an exception.